# Why did Cypher say they were going to kill Neo?

Tags: the-matrix

In the beginning of the first movie, in the first conversation, between Cypher and Trinity, he says:

> **Cypher**: We're going to kill him, understand?
>   **Trinity:** Morpheus believes he is the One.
>   **Cypher:** Do you?

Why did Cypher said that? Was it a habit to kill potential red pills? Was Neo considered to be a threat, so he needed to be killed if he was not the One?

Comment: I always interpreted this to mean that they were going to be putting Neo into a very dangerous situation  in which he would probably be killed.

Comment: I apply to Jaydee. I always thought they will kill him, when he is getting flushed out of this human plantation. C'mon, he's a computer user and those guys are pretty fragile!

Comment: In the original script there had already been five or six "the One"'s. Guess what happened to them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of interpreting Cypher's statement literally it should be interpreted as "what we are doing has a high risk of resulting in Neo's death".

This is true in general since Neo is older than most people who are unplugged from the Matrix, and Morpheus explains that

> We have a rule. We never free a mind once it's reached a certain age. It's **dangerous**, the mind has trouble letting go.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/transcript/)**</sub>

The danger posed by an attempt to "free" a mind includes possible death. This is a fact confirmed by the comic [Saviors](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Saviors), in which the parents of an adult red pill operative die because they are unplugged from the Matrix and were already too old (H/T @Valorum).

Of course, Trinity knows of this danger and doesn't need to be reminded by Cypher. However, Cypher has two ulterior reasons to say this.

### 1. Cypher was betraying the crew and covering up his involvement in Neo's likely death as a result of the betrayal.

Here's the dialogue you quoted along with the rest of the conversation:

> **Cypher**: We're going to kill him, understand?
>
> **Trinity:** Morpheus believes he is the One.
>
> **Cypher:** Do you?
>
> **Trinity:** It doesn't matter what I believe.
>
> **Cypher:** You don't, do you?
>
> **Trinity:** Did you hear that?
>
> **Cypher:** Hear what?
>
> **Trinity:** Are you sure this line is clean?
>
> **Cypher:** Yeah, of course I'm sure.
>
> **Trinity:** I better go.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/transcript/)**</sub>

Cypher was in the process of letting the Agents trace the line between him and Trinity. Later, after Trinity has escaped, the Agents have the following conversation:

> **Agent Brown:** She got out.
>
> **Agent Smith:** Doesn't matter.
>
> **Agent Brown:** The informant is real.
>
> **Agent Smith:** Yes.
>
> **Agent Jones:** We have the name of their next target.
>
> **Agent Brown:** The name is Neo.
>
> **Agent Smith:** We'll need a search running.
>
> **Agent Jones:** It's already begun.
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/transcript/)**</sub>

The informant is, of course, Cypher. And he has proved to the Agents that he is a true informant.

Cypher expected Neo to die since Cypher did not believe Neo was The One, and Cypher was betraying the crew. Cypher tells Trinity that they're going to kill Neo to raise Trinity's expectations that Neo will not be saved and will die during the process of trying to release him from the Matrix. This will help prevent her from suspecting his betrayal as the cause of Neo's death.

### 2. Cypher is infatuated with Trinity and attempting to undermine Trinity's belief that Neo is The One.

Cypher repeatedly attempts to convince Trinity that Neo is not The One. If Cypher can convince Trinity that Neo is not The One then, in his mind, she may fall in love with him instead. But as Cypher points out:

> I mean, how can he be the One if he's dead?
>
> <sub>**[transcript for *The Matrix*](http://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix/transcript/)**</sub>

Again, if Trinity expects that Neo will die then she will not think he is The One.

### Hidden Meanings

There are also two hidden meanings in Cypher's words. Neo symbolically dies twice in *The Matrix*. The first is when he is unplugged from the Matrix and "reborn" in the real world. The second is when Neo (who is not The One yet) dies at Agent Smith's hands but is resurrected as The One. Cypher obviously does not say that Neo will be killed for these reasons, but his line is for the audience's benefit -- by releasing Neo from the Matrix, they *did* kill him symbolically (and twice).

Comment: There is also the implication that Neo is older than the usual "red pill", and that most people, when removed from the Matrix, do not survive.

Comment: @JimGreen Yes, Neo is older than most people unplugged. But where is the implication that most people unplugged do not survive?

Comment: Of course, Neo has always been The One and is not reborn as The One. "You've got the gift, but it seems like you are waiting for something" -- Oracle. It took the experience of almost dying to make Neo realise this, but that doesn't change the fact that he has always been The One.

Comment: @user1129682 In the sense that Neo carries the code of the Prime Program, yes he has always been The One. But if you complete the quote from the Oracle she says "Your next life, maybe." She also says "Being The One is just like being in love. No one needs to tell you you are in love, you just know it..." So symbolically Neo was not yet The One.

Comment: @Null : Morpheus "I feel I owe you an apology. We have a rule. We never free a mind once it's reached a certain age. It's dangerous, the mind has trouble letting go." Later: Neo "If you're killing in the Matrix, you die here?" Morpheus "Your body cannot live without the mind."  Given those two statements from Morpheus, I would assume that if a person is released from the Matrix passed a certain age, they usually die.

Comment: @JimGreen I see your point now. I interpret it as saying that there is a high risk of death when unplugging older people (like Neo), but I wouldn't say that it means most people unplugged from the Matrix die as long as most people unplugged are young enough. Since Neo is older he does have a high risk of death. I'll incorporate this point into my answer. Thanks!

Comment: What's the reasoning behind "If Cypher can convince Trinity that Neo is not The One then, in his mind, she may fall in love with him instead." Are you assuming Trinity have told Cypher what the Oracle told her?

Comment: @Huangism No, she probably didn't tell him. But Cypher is nearly invisible as a sexual interest next to the man who is The One. Cypher clearly notices Trinity's interest in Neo both sexually and as possibly being The One (he tells her to look into "those big pretty eyes" as he's about to try to kill Neo). Moreover, if Neo is The One then he can't die -- but if Neo is not then he could die any minute and Cypher can compete for Trinity's affections at the same level.

Comment: @Null - It's shown in the Matrix Webcomic [Saviors](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Saviors) that an older mind, if unplugged from the matrix, will die.

Comment: @Valorum I don't have that comic (and the Matrix Wiki says it has *not* been published online), but it looks like Hitch's parents are the older minds that died when they were unplugged from the Matrix? I want to make sure I have it right before I add it to my answer.

Comment: @Null - It was commissioned exclusively by the Wachowskis for the Matrix Comics (Volume II). Yes, Hitch's parents are the older minds. Set in the world of the Matrix (but post-Neo's death) he tries to free them but they die.

Comment: @Null - It's here if you want to read it; http://imgur.com/a/xc34i)

Comment: @Valorum Thanks, I've updated my answer. That comic also has applications for other Q&A's, too...

Answer (score -3):

Trinity, Cypher, Morpheus, and the red pill resistance are more evil than the agents, and were harming Neo's life in secret.

Trinity and cypher are both traders.

Remember Morpheus said it was "they" (the red pill resistance) that scorched the sky and made life complicated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This all seems very unlikely.  Can you supply some exact quotes, especially about the last statement, that support your reading?

Comment: this answer is clearly just sentient AI revisionist history painting the humans as the real enemy and the machines as good. I for one welcome our new robot overloads.... ;)